# How to reset a variable/sql record once a month automatically with asp.net/sql ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, reset

I need to reset the value of a specific column in a table to some specific value per month. 
eg: allowances column should be reset to 10,000 at the beginning of each month.
(using sql-server and asp.net) 
How to achieve such kind of a task ?

Comment: You could use a scheduled job via Sql Server Agent, but that wouldn't meet your requirement of involving an ASP website. To do that you would need a separate application, e.g. a Windows Service, to reach out and request a page from the website that would update the database that ... .

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a service, which will check your record once per day and reset it when needed
2. On user logon, check and reset
3. On Application start, check and reset. Also, a static class with timer, which will run the code at certain intervals

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have a process that would check date couple times per day (just to make sure) and update the data.

Problem is that you can’t create processes that are running in the background using only ASP.NET – you need a windows service that would be hosted on the server in order to achieve this.

Here are several other options you can try.

Modify Session_Start method in Globl.asax to check date and modify data – this will make it so that first visitor who accesses application on the first day of the month triggers database reset.

Create a separate page that, when accessed, checks date and resets the data and then find some online service that can ping this page like once per day or on a given day of the month….

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql server integration services project and schrdule it as a batch job to run it every month,

inside the job you can use sql task to update the value